# How to click on <a> tag using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to scrape reviews off amazon.

After going on a particular product's page on amazon I want to click on the 'see all reviews' button. I did inspect element on the page, I found that the see all reviews button has this structure

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxEyR.png)

So I tried to find this element using the class name `a-link-emphasis a-text-bold`.

This is the code I wrote

```
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service('C:\\coding\\chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options)
driver.get(url)
sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-link-emphasis a-text-bold').click()
sleep(5)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

But this returns me the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".a-link-emphasis a-text-bold"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-link-emphasis.a-text-bold').click()
```

By class expects single class not multiple but you can use the above syntax , remove space with . as it uses css under the hood, or use :

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-link-emphasis.a-text-bold').click()
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="a-link-emphasis a-text-bold"]').click()
```